# how to send email from an instance without using sendgrid?

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, google, google-compute-engine

My project up and beta running on google compute engine. I want to set-up email server. For that i followed http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-in-centos-6/

I edited `/etc/postfix/main.cf` exactley how they mentioned and here is few more details

```
myhostname = mx.audiworld.com
mydomain = audiworld.com
mynetworks = <compute-instance-ip>,127.0.0.1/8
```

when I issue `telnet localhost 25` I am getting below error

```
[root@myinstance-1 ~]# telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

but `namp localhost` gives me

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-11-06 09:48 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000011s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
21/tcp  open  ftp
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
110/tcp open  pop3
143/tcp open  imap
465/tcp open  smtps
993/tcp open  imaps
995/tcp open  pop3s

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.42 seconds
```

so the smtp port is 465 right ? then `telnet localhost 465` finally got it working

Ok this what google is telling

> Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587 but you can still set up your instances to send mail through ports 587 and 465 using servers provided through partner services, such as SendGrid. This document discusses how to set up your instances to send email using SendGrid.

but I don't want `sendgrid` to manage email . without using sendgrid how to setup Email server.?

Comment: Is Postfix running? Check the [`inet_interfaces`](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#inet_interfaces) directive.  `netstat -tlnp` is better than `nmap` for finding what is listening on your local box.

Comment: @Ladadadada thanks! i given `netstat -tlnp` oh .. there i can't see postfix in `PID/Program name` what should i do ?

Comment: @Ladadadada: There is no point in getting postfix to run if you can't the mail away from your system.

Comment: @rajasimon: Postfix doesn't have a process called `postfix`. There are `master`,`qmgr`,`tslmgr`,`pickup` and maybe others, depending on your config.

Comment: i can see two master there `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5493/master`

Comment: Post your `master.cf`. But note: Getting Postfix to listen on port 25 won't help you to work around the port filter on Google's side.

Comment: @SvW I didn't read the bit about it being on Google Compute Engine.  I saw *instance* in the title and assumed AWS.  My bad.

Comment: Your options are to use a service Google approves of, or to not use Google Compute Engine. Either way we can't be of any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The text is clear: **Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587**.

If that doesn't work for you, you are on the wrong platform.

Comment: I don't want to depend on another email hosting platform like sendgrid. All i want to in google compute engine itself or is there any other way around that ?

Comment: **There is no way around that**. If you don't like the restrictions Google put on their Compute Engine product, don't use it. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Note that you can use any service that offers non-standard ports. These days, port 2525 is becoming quite popular among 3rd party MTA providers.